# How to smooth / filter a function in a n-dimensional space using python?

Tags: numpy, filtering, smoothing, ndimage

I have function defined in an n-dimensional space which I represent with (X,Y), where X is an array of size mxn containing the input features and Y an array of size mx1 containing the output. So there are m points in an d-dimensional space with m >> n.

I would like to smooth the values of Y (output). In the case of 1 or 2 dimensions I would probably use smoothed splines.  In the case of n dimensions I do not really know... I thought about the median filter in scipy (median_filter), but it is not clear to me how to find neighbours in X and fetch the corresponding values in Y to compute the median.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean *n*-dimensional space?

Comment: I would keep looking at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters, there are smoothing filters for n-d operations.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: yes

Comment: @sea_hydro: here are some interesting filters, but I do not know how to use them given my representation of the data, I do not have a grid of function values which I can just provide as input. I guess I need a sort of meshgrid?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scipy.spatial.KDTree` to find points in some radius and then find the median value of Y.

Or maybe use some regression method in sklearn, such as [Support Vector Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html#example-svm-plot-svm-regression-py)